# Facebook's Graph API posts are not visible?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to publish posts on a page using Facebook API. I’m an admin of the page.

I’ve done these steps:

1. Created an app in dev mode
2. Received page access token
3. Made a post using Facebook Graph API

A post appeared on the page. But unfortunately no one sees it. Only me.

What am I missing? Is it because the app in dev mode? If yes, is there any way to post on a page without app review?

Comment: Yes, your app needs to be in live mode, otherwise all content created through it will only be available to users with a role in the app. Regarding review - you’ll have to check whether you can still grant all required permissions with your admin account in live mode, if you don’t get it reviewed.